# Can we use Dynamics NAV instead of Tally.erp

Tags: dynamics-nav, tally

I want to know if I can use Dynamics NAV instead of Tally.ERP S/W for posting groups and ledgers and vouchers from my ERP Application.(Integrating my App with NAV instead of Tally). If yes can anyone please guide me how to do. I want to post Groups & Ledgers and (1.Journal 2.Cash Payment 3.Bank Payment 4.Receipt 5.Contra Vouchers) from my ERP.

Answer (score 0):

Integration is very simple with NAV. You may do the following:

1. Output your data files from your application. It is very easy to build NAV Codeunits that read from your data file, and update NAV accordingly.
2. Use NAV Web Services to directly interact with your application in real time. Again, this is very very simple with NAV. Just create a Web Service Job from the NAV Client. Then, Simply make HTTP Request from your application, with your data. What you can do is call codeunits when the web services are called, and do the posting. It will take at most a few hours to set it up from NAV.